# TypeScript code doesn't give an error during compilation but doesn't work as intended

Tags: typescript

I'm facing an issue while executing TypeScript code from a GitHub repository (https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Mastering-TypeScript-Fourth-Edition/tree/main/ch07). Although the files compile without errors when I use the tsc command, I encounter errors like "trace command not found" when I try to open any of the files that use the ErrorHelper module from the created dist/jsFiles folder, by executing the node ErrorHelperSample.js command. Can someone please assist me in running the code from this repository? I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

EDIT: Added an example

I do `tsc` command in the `ch07` directory. Then when I do `node declaration_file_samples.js`, I get the `trace not found` error.

Comment: please include [mcve] in the question itself

Comment: Hey @depperm , sorry about that. I added what exactly I was doing.

Comment: In `decleration_file_samples.ts` there are 4 calls to `trace` although this is not imported from any other packages or file in the repository. Include the definition of `trace` inline or import it from the appropriate file/pkg.